# Image mapping responsive design

Tags: responsive-design

I have a responsive wordpress theme and have designed an image with a image mapped active area which when clicks reveals a content div.

When re-sizing window the active area moves (of course) as the image size and position is different. I have tried a plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/responsive-image-maps/ but this doesn't seem to work unless I am failing to interpret what I am supposed to do.

Below is the html and javascript call

`<map name="circle"><area shape="circle" coords="58,290,53" href="javascript:unhide('welcome');"><div class="columns different sidebar right"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="../different.png" usemap="circle" /></div></a>
    </map>`

Any ideas where I should be putting the coords for the different media sizes? In the CSS, witihin the html calling the @media function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321067/dynamically-resizing-image-maps-and-images.