# Dynamically position tooltips to an image?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, marker, jquery-tooltip, tooltipster

So I've been trying to get something like this to work however I can't seem to get the tooltips to position responsive. Below is the website example:

- http://hypebeast.com/2016/1/essentials-dolly-cohen-celebrity-grill-maker

From what I gather each time the page loads the tooltip divs inherit an inline style of position absolute with a set top and left. How would I go about recreating this effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "position responsive" ?

Comment: I can work out how to position them normally but is there a way to pin it to an exact point on the image so if I resized the screen I'm looking at and the image got smaller it was still pinned to the same area of the image?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use image map areas, and use a javascript script that will reposition the areas on windows resize, as suggested on this page : [Dynamically resizing Image-maps and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321067/dynamically-resizing-image-maps-and-images)

And then create the tooltips on these "responsive" map areas.

Comment: Thanks for that eventually got it working! Sorry about the late reply.