# How to place multiple invisible links over one picture in html?

Tags: html, image, layout, click

I am making a website using flask and want an image where clicking different parts of this will take you to different links. Is this possible? Even somewhere I could start figuring out something like this would be great thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickable areas of image - even when screen changes sizes html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194182/clickable-areas-of-image-even-when-screen-changes-sizes-html) You haven't mentioned changing screen sizes yourself, but I think the linked question and its answers still provide a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the `area` tag in HTML: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the back end you use (Flask or otherwise), you are looking for [an HTML image map](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp) - a well established concept since the early days of the web.