# Dynamically resizing Image-maps and images with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, maphilight

I m using [ng-maphilight](https://tylerrick.github.io/ng-maphilight/) to segment my picture but the area are not responsive with my picture.

sample code :

```
<mat-card class="col-md-8">
   <maphilight id="1" [config]="config"  [hidden]="hidden">
      <img src="assets/img/imageProjet/img1.jpg" class="col-md-12">
      <map>
          <area shape="poly" coords="439, 67, 506, 68, 506, 189, 578, 191, 590, 222, 623, 303, 546, 298, 539, 257, 506, 256, 507, 300, 459, 297, 457, 313, 446, 317, 443, 517, 374, 522, 382, 390, 382, 339, 381, 324, 353, 319, 360, 187, 434, 188" />
          <area shape="poly" coords="513, 32, 512, 72, 510, 183, 580, 185, 592, 219, 595, 110, 687, 106, 657, 19, 597, 16, 521, 21" />
      </map>
   </maphilight>
</mat-card>
```

so I was searching for a solution to dynamically resize an image map and its areas. I only found a solution for jQuery  [jQuery-rwdImageMaps](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)

But couldn't find it on angular !!!
here is another solution found on stackoverflow : [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321067/dynamically-resizing-image-maps-and-images) But i couldn't convert it to angular,
any help please ? How can I realize this in Angular?